# Exposing WebService method issues

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I don't understand why I have web service methods exposed which shouldn't be the case according to JAX-WS specification (as I understand it).

I've created a simple test web service with implicit SEI:

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface TestServiceSEI 
{
    public String helloTest();
    @WebMethod public String helloTest2();
}
```

The goal is to make helloTest() **not** be exposed in WebService and helloTest2() be exposed in WebService.  I then implement this SIB:

I spicifically omit endpointInterface parameter to make this implicit SEI.  My understanding is that with implicit SEI, in order to expose web service, I must use @WebMethod annotation, any methods that are not annoted with @WebMethod in implicit SEI shouldn't be exposed in WebService?

Hence:

```
@WebService 
public class TestServiceSIB implements TestServiceSEI
{
    @Override
    //this method should not be exposed? 
    public String helloTest() 
    {
        return "HELLO WORLD";
    }

    //only this method should be exposed     
    @Override
    public String helloTest2()
    {
        return "HELLO WEB SERVICE";
    }   
}
```

When I publish the WebService:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9876/ws", new TestServiceSIB());
}
```

Nonetheless, I see all methods exposed in operation WebService:

```
<operation name="helloTest">
    <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </input>
        <output>
           <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
<operation name="helloTest2">
    <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <input>
           <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </input>
        <output>
           <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </output>
</operation>
```

No matter what I try, I always have all methods showing in the WebService, but according to JAX-WS specs methods get exposed only under specific circumstances which I am trying to avoid and yet they get exposed anyways.  I am trying to follow specification and hide certain methods but they keep showing.

Could somebody kindly explain why I keep having helloTest() exposed when it shouldn't?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to annotate the public method you do not want to expose
with the annotation

```
@WebMethod(exclude=true)
```